# Does python logging.FileHandler use block buffering by default?

Tags: python, logging, output-buffering

The `logging` handler classes have a flush() method.

And looking at the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py), `logging.FileHandler` does not pass a specific buffering mode when calling `open()`.  Therefore when you write to a log file, it will be buffered using a default block size.

Is that correct?

---

It surprises me, because when I manage my own system, I am used to watching log files as a live (or [near-live](https://github.com/Icinga/icinga2/blob/v2.10.4/lib/base/streamlogger.cpp#L75)) view on the system.  For this use case, line-buffering is desired.  Also, traditional syslog() to a logging daemon does not buffer messages.

---

I am interested in Python versions 2.7 and 3.7.

Comment: Small note on `stderr` when tty, it tends to default to being unbuffered, unlike stdout which would usually be by default line-buffered. No idea about `systemd`/`journald`, but I would assume it would make sense to change buffering of any `stderr` capture/redirection to be the same (unbuffered).

Comment: @OndrejK. the answer to my Q is "no" - I read the code wrong, I'll write it up.  Regarding the buffering of stderr, I think python3 has surprising behaviour.  I was going off the doc that says it can be block-buffered, and I think the doc is accurate.  More discussion in [this python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue13597).

Comment: Yeah, I looked up at the underlying code... py2.7 `a` mode will basically whatever your system would do for `openat` call. py3.x `a` is text mode, so you will get buffered text io (on not tty block, on tty line by default), the file handle bellow `openat` is same (except for `|O_CLOEXEC`, "non-inheritable" fd essentially), but buffering comes from `io` module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not really.  It will flush each individual message, which is what you want.

FileHandler inherits from StreamHandler.  StreamHandler calls self.flush() after every write() to the stream.

The flush() method starts to make more sense if you look at `logging.MemoryHandler`.  For programs which want to add buffering, MemoryHandler allows wrapping another handler, and buffering a set number of messages.  It will also flush immediately on messages above a set severity level.  `logging` does not include a handler which automatically flushes every second or so, but you could always write one yourself.

The flush calls in StreamHandler *also* mean that it does what you want, if your program is run as a `systemd` service and you log to `stderr`.  Python 3 requires flushes in this case.  Python 3 currently uses block buffering for stderr when it is not a TTY.  See [discussion on Python issue 13597](https://bugs.python.org/issue13597#msg149419)

### Possible reason for my mistake

I think I was confused by the StreamHandler code.  If the user never needed to call the flush() method, why would StreamHandler define a non-empty, publicly documented implementation?

I think I was assuming too much, and I did not allow for how inheritance (argh) is used here.  E.g. the base Handler class has an empty flush() method, but StreamHandler does not want to inherit that because it has a weird docstring "This version does nothing and is intended to be implemented by subclasses".